# uploading files from Laravel to azure blob storage

Tags: laravel, azure, azure-blob-storage, inertiajs

I was given a task to maintain a Laravel project with Vue.js (inertia) (not very experienced with both). Now we need to switch the host to Azure and I am stuck on the file storage. Specifically, I am not sure **how to upload files from Laravel to the Blob**. I am already using https://github.com/matthewbdaly/laravel-azure-storage which is a convenient way to connect the driver.

My driver in filesystem.php (details are correct):

```
'azure' => [
            'driver'    => 'azure',
            'name'      => env('AZURE_STORAGE_NAME'),
            'key'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'),
            'container' => env('AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER'),
            'url'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_URL'),
            'prefix'    => null,
        ],
```

my controller:

```
$url = request()->file->store('azure');
```

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to SO .. is it `base64` image?

Comment: Please try to use code: `store('<path>','<file_name>','azure')` : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#specifying-a-disk

Comment: No, it's not a base64 img. I am not trying to store it in the database but the Storage explorer in Azure. I tried specifying the disk. It didn't work for me. I tested giving the URL for the blob as 
 <path>  and also the root ( / ). Both options did not work.

Comment: Now I noticed that I get a  Status:500 on network saying:  "The provided account key '' is not a valid base64 string. It has to pass the check 'base64_decode(<user_account_key>, true)'.". Any Ideas?

Comment: @brpetrov Could you please tell me how you get an account key?

Comment: I get the key from Storage Account-> Access Keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to my test, we should use double quotes to expand the access key in `.evn`.

For example

1. Add this in `.env` file

```
AZURE_STORAGE_NAME=<account name>
AZURE_STORAGE_KEY="<account key>"
AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER=
AZURE_STORAGE_URL=https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/
```

2. Add this to the `disks` section of `config/filesystems.php`:

```
'azure' => [
            'driver'    => 'azure',
            'name'      => env('AZURE_STORAGE_NAME'),
            'key'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'),
            'container' => env('AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER'),
            'url'       => env('AZURE_STORAGE_URL'),
            'prefix'    => null,
        ],
```

3. Uplaod code

```
  public function fileUpload(Request $req){
        $req->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048'
        ]);

      

        if($req->file()) {
            $fileName = time().'_'.$req->file->getClientOriginalName();
            // save file to azure blob virtual directory uplaods in your container
            $filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads/', $fileName, 'azure');

            return back()
            ->with('success','File has been uploaded.')

        }
   }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This looks like the way of doing it! I need to postpone it for a few days but I will tell you asap. One thing to ask is: Inside azure storage-> CORS -> You are supposed to allow origins (domains) that are allowed to access it. Did you create a domain to test or you did it in localhost? I read somewhere that your app won't be able to access it unless you specify it's domain.

Comment: @brpetrov. I test it on localhost, it is ok for me.

Comment: @jimXu It is showing "Driver [azure] is not supported.", Can you please help me?

Comment: Same issue with @DevendraSharma . I am getting "Driver [azure] is not supported."

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @Jim Xu, tested out the logic from your example and it works great.
If someone stumbled upon this, by default azure blob containers are private.
To serve file or images publicly for your Laravel app, **don't forget to change the container's access level to either Blob or Container**

Comment: This should be rather a comment to the @Jim Xu's answer.

Comment: @Robson sorry, my reputation level have not reached 50 yet so I cannot comment on other answers